# how to configure NFS client to bypass VFS cache

Tags: centos7, nfs

I have a site for multimedia conversion.
to separate the CPU workload I decided to use 2 servers.

-1 server with web server and NFS server

-1 server with NFS client acting as an ffmpeg converter.

I noticed that NFS does not write files directly but transfers them later.
what should immediately transfer to the server disk are small TXT files with the conversion status, but I notice that the file is transferred only when the conversion is 100%, therefore only when the process has finished.
is there an option to write files directly to the remote disk?
this is the configuration of nfs:

on /etc/exports file (NFS server):

```
/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs       46.x.x.x(rw,async,no_wdelay,nohide,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/Downloads     46.x.x.x(rw,async,no_wdelay,nohide,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

on /etc/fstab file (NFS client)

```
138.x.x.x:/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs    /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs   nfs nolock,nfsvers=3 0 0
138.x.x.x:/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/Downloads    /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/Downloads   nfs nolock,nfsvers=3 0 0
```

Comment: Why do you say NFS does not write files directly? Generally speaking that's not correct.

Comment: as @davidgo suggested, better to change the title to "how to configure NFS client to bypass VFS cache"

Answer (score 0):

There is no mount option to bypass file system cache under Linux.

The only lagal way to do it is to force your application to use **O_DIRECT** open flag as POSIX standard required.